# module re regular expression working as expected in console window, but not "in eclipse"

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Current wisdom: unicode / WinAnsiEncoding toothing problem. `re.compile(<rex>, re.DEBUG)` helped.
I'm trying to match PDF (PostScript) "standard 14" font names using python 3.5 module `re`. Works like a charm in a console window if ready to  accept `|` not being greedy:

```
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> standard14Names = (
...         'Times-Roman',                'Symbol',
...         'Times-(Bold)?(Italic)?',     'ZapfDingbats',
...         '(Courier|Helvetica)-?(Bold)?(Oblique)?',  # 'Helvetica-?(Bold)?(Oblique)?',
...         'Arial,?(Bold)?(Italic)?'
...         )
>>> standard14 = re.compile("|".join(standard14Names))
>>> print(standard14.search("/Times-Roman"))
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 12), match='Times-Roman'>
>>> print(standard14.search("/Times-BoldItalic"))
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 17), match='Times-BoldItalic'>
>>> print(standard14.search("/Courier-Italic"))
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 9), match='Courier-'>
>>> print(standard14.search("/Helvetica-Bold"))
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 15), match='Helvetica-Bold'>
>>> print(standard14.search("/Courier-Oblique"))
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 16), match='Courier-Oblique'>
```

(I'm aware of the possibility of "false positives" from `Arial,?(Bold)?(Italic)?` & co..)
However, running "in eclipse" (4.6.3 PyDev 5.8):

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version)
3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
>>> print(standard14.search("/Times-Roman"))
None
>>> print(standard14.search("/Courier-Oblique"))
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 8), match='Courier'>
>>> print(standard14.search("/Helvetica-Bold"))
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 10), match='Helvetica'>
```

(Times-Roman is particularly funny, I even tried "backslashing the dash")
I'm fresh out of ideas.

Comment: Is Eclipse using the same Python version (and installation) as your console window?

Comment: And you're sure you pasted the exact same lines in for `standard14Names` and `standard14`?

Comment: Well, I'm stumped. I mean, I can think of other `re` libraries that might do this, but even if you managed to import one of them shadowing `re`, there's no way you'd get an `_sre.SRE_Match` object out of one of them, so…

Comment: There's no chance you did something silly like attach a `U` flag, right?

Comment: One more thing: can you try `standard14 = re.compile("|".join(standard14Names), re.DEBUG` in both environments, verify that they're identical, and, if they're not identical, post the Eclipse one?

Comment: The `r` won't matter here. Neither the individual strings you're `join`ing nor the `'|'` have any backslashes. (Of course `r` is a good idea anyway in case that's no longer true after some future edit.) I was referring to the `UNGREEDY` flag, which I think isn't even documented (and maybe not even exposed?) in the `re` module.

Comment: Lo and behold, the dashes show up as `LITERAL 8722` (instead of 45) in eclipse. Thanks a bundle.

Comment: So they're U+2212, which is Unicode MINUS SIGN, in Eclipse, but ASCII hyphens in the console. I can see how you'd accidentally put Unicode minus characters into Eclipse, but how did it get transformed into ASCII in a copy-paste?

Comment: Anyway, I think at this point you can either write and accept your own answer, or close your own question (depending on whether you think anyone else might run into this problem).

Comment: So much for copying from standards documents to avoid typing errors…

Comment: For a standard presumably written by Adobe, I'm not that surprised. Looking exactly right when printed out is far more important than such silly things as being able to copy normative text, right? One of their published specs looked like a plain-text RFC-format file when you looked at it in the browser, until you looked at the address bar and saw that it was a PDF—how else can they make sure you don't accidentally read it in an ugly font like Courier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here turned out to be that the original `standard14Names` in the source code was using Unicode `MINUS SIGN` characters (`U+2212`) instead of ASCII hyphens (`U+002D`). The fix is to just replace the `-` characters in the source with `-`.

---

You'll notice that these characters visually look almost identical, making it nearly impossible to debug. Even more of a problem when one is in Eclipse and the other in a terminal window, so they may not even be in the same font…

Also, it's a bit baffling that, when copying to the clipboard, Eclipse apparently converted the Unicode text to ASCII using a `replace`-type handler. Or maybe this is the terminal doing it on paste, or even X11 or Windows or whatever sits between the two?

Anyway, if some future searcher has a similar problem, here's the smart way to debug it: Just dump out the codepoints of the strings in each environment, something like this:

```
' '.join(hex(ord(ch)) for name in standard14Names for ch in name)
```

It should be pretty easy to look over the two and see that one of them is pure ASCII (two-byte hex codepoints), while the other one has a bunch of `0x2212` values.

Once you spot that, you can look for the first difference, and you'll quickly see that every `0x2212` lines up with an `0x2d` in the other version, at which point (assuming you don't know the Unicode tables by heart) you can google U+2212 and figure out what's going on.

I actually recommended a dumber first step—it worked anyway, but it was more effort for the OP. You can dump the compilation information for the regex objects by executing `re.compile("|".join(standard14Names), re.DEBUG)` in both environments. That doesn't return a string, it actually dumps the output to the terminal, so you have to scroll back and copy it all into a text file to do anything useful with it. Also, it's going to be very long. But anyway, if you put both versions into text files and `diff` them, you'll see that every diff is `LITERAL 8722` vs. `LITERAL 45`, and those are the decimal values for `0x2212` and `0x2d`, so we've gotten the same information as in the previous version.